# I paid to download the os and it only allowed me to get the 64 bit version. Need the 32 bit version please send a link. Gary Arey

Tags: download

I paid for elementary os and it provided the 64 bit version. I need the 32 bit version. Is there a place I can find this?

Comment: It's not really what you want to hear but now Arch Linux has stopped releasing versions for 32-bit, it's probably around a year before most major distros stop creating 32-bit releases. http://www.pcworld.com/article/3164876/linux/arch-linux-pulls-the-plug-on-32-bit.html

Answer (score 2):

There is no 32bit Loki. If you need 32bit you'll have to run Freya.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/elementaryos/files/stable/elementaryos-freya-i386.20150411.iso/download